# How to access current_user in partial of public_activity gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, public-activity

When I m trying to access current_user in partial file it will contains nil value.

I used devise gem for login process.
I also used public_activity gem for generating notification.

I have notification controller as below.

```
def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.all      
end
```

In views/notifications/index.html.erb

```
<%= render @activities %>
```

Now in views/public_activity/commontator_comment/_create.html.erb

in this partial I want to access current_user but it contains nil value.

I didn't understand what was the problem.

please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In application controller you need to include a module

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
  include PublicActivity::StoreController       

end
```

This records the controller on each request allowing us to access it from the models. We can do this in the model by adding an owner option to tracked.

```
tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller.current_user }
```

You can read in details about this here http://asciicasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity

Answer (score 0):

Example for track User.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include PublicActivity::StoreController

  [.....]

  # Only if devise is not used
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

activities_controller.rb

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Common
  [...]
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController      

  def my_method
    [...]
      respond_to do |format|
      if @my_object.save
      @my_object.create_activity :create, owner: current_user 
    [...] 
  end
end
```

app/views/activities/index.html.haml

```
- @activities.each do |a|
  = render_activity a
```

others views

```
/app
  /views
    /public_activity
      /user
        _create.html.haml
        _destroy.html.haml
        [_all_methods.html.haml]
```

view example

```
 = a.owner.name + " " + a.owner.firstname
 created the user
 = a.trackable.name + " " + a.trackable.firstname + " (" + a.trackable.email + ")"
```